# Sorting array of JSON objects by properties with an order of importance

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have a bunch of songs stored in an array of JavaScript objects. It looks like this:

```
var library = [
{ "title": "40 Years Later",       "album": "Tears of Steel", "year": 2012, "track": 1, "disk": 1, "time": 31  },
{ "title": "The Dome",             "album": "Tears of Steel", "year": 2012, "track": 2, "disk": 1, "time": 311 },
{ "title": "The Battle",           "album": "Tears of Steel", "year": 2012, "track": 3, "disk": 1, "time": 123 },
{ "title": "End Credits",          "album": "Tears of Steel", "year": 2012, "track": 4, "disk": 1, "time": 103 },
{ "title": "The Wires",           "album": "Elephants Dream", "year": 2006, "track": 1, "disk": 1, "time": 75  },
{ "title": "Typewriter Dance",    "album": "Elephants Dream", "year": 2006, "track": 2, "disk": 1, "time": 70  },
{ "title": "The Safest Place",    "album": "Elephants Dream", "year": 2006, "track": 3, "disk": 1, "time": 45  },
{ "title": "Emo Creates",         "album": "Elephants Dream", "year": 2006, "track": 4, "disk": 1, "time": 60  },
{ "title": "End Title",           "album": "Elephants Dream", "year": 2006, "track": 5, "disk": 1, "time": 91  },
{ "title": "Teaser Music",        "album": "Elephants Dream", "year": 2006, "track": 6, "disk": 1, "time": 75  },
{ "title": "Ambience",            "album": "Elephants Dream", "year": 2006, "track": 7, "disk": 1, "time": 110 },
{ "title": "Snow Fight",                   "album": "Sintel", "year": 2010, "track": 1, "disk": 1, "time": 107 },
{ "title": "Finding Scales / Chicken Run", "album": "Sintel", "year": 2010, "track": 2, "disk": 1, "time": 107 },
{ "title": "The Ziggurat",                 "album": "Sintel", "year": 2010, "track": 3, "disk": 1, "time": 78  },
{ "title": "Expedition",                   "album": "Sintel", "year": 2010, "track": 4, "disk": 1, "time": 93  },
{ "title": "Dragon Blood Tree",            "album": "Sintel", "year": 2010, "track": 5, "disk": 1, "time": 47  },
{ "title": "Cave Fight / Lament",          "album": "Sintel", "year": 2010, "track": 6, "disk": 1, "time": 145 },
{ "title": "I Move On (Sintel's Song)",    "album": "Sintel", "year": 2010, "track": 7, "disk": 1, "time": 169 },
{ "title": "Circling Dragons",             "album": "Sintel", "year": 2010, "track": 8, "disk": 1, "time": 28  },
{ "title": "Trailer Music",                "album": "Sintel", "year": 2010, "track": 9, "disk": 1, "time": 44  }
];
```

I need to sort by properties in both alphabetical and numerical order. There are lots of articles and questions on StackOverflow that cover sorting by a single value, and some that seem to cover multiple values but they have no order or importance.

I need to sort each object (song) by several values where each value is of a lower importance rank. For example:

> `album` name *(alphabetical)* > `disk` number *(numerical)* > `track` number *(numerical)* > `title` *(alphabetical)* > etc.

This means that albums are together where each album is in alphabetical order. In each album are songs sorted by the disk number, so all songs in disk 1 are at the top, then all songs in disk 2, etc. Inside each grouping of disk numbers are songs sorted by track number. If there are multiple songs with the same track number, or no track number exists, they will be sorted by song title in alphabetical order. More properties can be given if track title is also the same.

Capitalization should not matter, and it should sort like normal alphabetical sorting would (if it started with a number, that would go before letters, and special characters would have their place like in traditional sorting).

I have tried using this code (which has hard-coded sort values and lacks disk numbers) but it is *only* sorting by the inner-most property in the code, track number.

```
library.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.album === b.album) {
        if (a.track === b.track) {
            var x = a.title.toLowerCase();
            var y = b.title.toLowerCase();
            return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
        }
        var x = a.track;
        var y = b.track;
        return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return a.album.toLowerCase() - b.album.toLowerCase();
});
```

I am looking for a function that will rearrange the `library` array so that it is sorted as described above given something along the lines of the following input:

```
sort(library, [ "album", "disk", "track", "title" ]);
```

Individual values should also be able to be sorted in a descending order, maybe looking something like `-album` or `["album", true]`. Syntax is flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function like this:

```
function priority(opt) {
    if (!(opt instanceof Array)) {
        opt = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    }
    return function (a, b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; ++i) {
            var option = opt[i];
            if (typeof option === 'string') {
                option = [option, '+'];
            }
            if (option.length < 2) {
                option[1] = '+';
            }
            if (a[option[0]] !== b[option[0]]) {
                if (a[option[0]] === undefined) return 1;
                if (b[option[0]] === undefined) return -1;
                if (typeof a[option[0]] === 'string' || typeof b[option[0]] === 'string') {
                    return (option[1] === '+' ? String(a[option[0]]).toLowerCase() < String(b[option[0]]).toLowerCase() : String(a[option[0]]).toLowerCase() > String(b[option[0]]).toLowerCase()) ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                    return (option[1] === '+' ? a[option[0]] < b[option[0]] : a[option[0]] > b[option[0]]) ? -1 : 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    };
}
```

it works like this:

```
library.sort(priority(['album', 'disk', ['title', '-']])
```

this will sort library by album ascending, then disk ascending, then title descending

Formal usage:

opt: array containing:

- string (sorts key 'string' in ascending order)

or

- array

  - 0: string (sorts key 'string')
  - 1: '-' or '+' for ascending or descending order (defaults to ascending)

I didn't implement it the exact way you said, because it would make keys beginning with `-` impossible to sort in ascending order.

EDIT:

alternate version, works with `'-album'` syntax:

```
function priority(opt) {
    if (!(opt instanceof Array)) {
        opt = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    }
    return function (a, b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; ++i) {
            var order = opt[i].substr(0, 1),
                key = opt[i].substr(1);
            if (order !== '-' && order !== '+') {
                key = opt[i];
                order = '+';
            }
            if (a[key] !== b[key]) {
                if (a[key] === undefined) return 1;
                if (b[key] === undefined) return -1;
                if (typeof a[key] === 'string' || typeof b[key] === 'string') {
                    return (order === '+' ? String(a[key]).toLowerCase() < String(b[key]).toLowerCase() : String(a[key]).toLowerCase() > String(b[key]).toLowerCase()) ? -1 : 1;
                } else {
                    return (order === '+' ? a[key] < b[key] : a[key] > b[key]) ? -1 : 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    };
}
```

to be used like this:

```
library.sort(priority(['album', '-year', '+title']));
or
library.sort(priority('album', '-year', '+title'));
```

Comment: forgot the `<` in the ternary expression

Comment: In your alternate syntax version, is the `+` optional?

Comment: yes, the `+` is optional. It is there to ensure that it is possible to have keys starting with `-` (just use `'+--keywithdash'` to sort such a key in ascending order and `'---keywithdash'` for descending)

Comment: Great idea. I never even thought about that!

Comment: now sorts strings as case-insensitive while preserving numbers and other types

Comment: added vararg support to first variant

Comment: added sorting and undefined fix

Comment: fixed bugs created by fix

Answer (score 3):

You can sort array of ojects with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript SQL library. It supports sorting with many fields in any order (like SQL).

For many sorts Alasql may be faster than other sort functions, because it compiles queries to JavaScript and save these compiled query function to cache.

```
var res = alasql('SELECT *, LCASE(album) AS lalbum, LCASE(title) as ltitle FROM ? \
     ORDER BY lalbum DESC, disk, ltrack, ltitle',[library]);
```

Here I created two additional fields (lalbum and ltitle) for sort text in case-insensitive way.

Try this example with you data [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/h765ddde/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.. one approach to the problem:

```
// This is kinda hacky, but it works
// "a" means do an alphabetical compare
// "n" means do a numeric compare.
var sortKeys = ["album", "a", "disk", "n", "track", "n", "title", "n"];

function byKey(ao, bo) {
    var l = sortKeys.length;
    var i = 0;
    var sortResult;

    // Walk through the keys  
    while (i < l) {
        // Get the field name
        var field = sortKeys[i];
        // Get the compare type
        var sortType = sortKeys[i + 1];

        // Get the values and force to string values
        var a = "" + ao[field];
        var b = "" + bo[field];

        console.log([field, sortType]);
        // Advance by two because we consume two array elements
        i += 2;

        // Our alphabletical compare
        if (sortType === "a") {
            if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) {
                return -1;
            }

            if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) {
                return +1;
            }

            if (a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase()) {
                // Ok, these fields match.  Restart the loop
                // So it will try the next sort criteria in.
                continue;
            }

            throw ("Should never actually get here.");
        }

        if (sortType === "n") {
            // Cheap numeric compare
            return +a - +b;
        }


    }

    // A total match across all fields
    return 0;

}

library.sort(byKey);

console.log(JSON.stringify(library, null, 2));
```

Comment: Can the numbers be turned into strings and allowed to be sorted in the same way? If there was an album starting in a number, that would cause problems.

Comment: It handles that now... though as long as the album name were in quotes, it would be a string regardless of content. However, I made a slight change so that a strict number would be converted to a string properly.  Likewise, anything flagged to be sorted as a number is forced to a number.

Comment: I should also note that capitalization should not matter. I'm not sure if it does in your solution.

Comment: I figured as much from your example code.  If you look you'll see I am doing a `toLowerCase()` in the comparisons.

Comment: +1 to thank you for the effort but I had to give it to Ferdi265 because he was first and his code was simpler and didn't require an alphabetical/numerical specification. But at least you get 10 points for your effort and thank you!